# How to add mid points in the react flow library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

I use the [reactflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactflow) library to build diagrams and I need to implement editing connection lines. For example, you click on a line and drag it somewhere and the path (svg) of the line changes appropriately.

[image]

On GitHub the exact same [question](https://github.com/xyflow/xyflow/discussions/1029) exists but it is [closed](https://github.com/xyflow/xyflow/issues/1623) and I cannot understand whether the problem is solved or not. Maybe you know how to add these midpoints or it is not supported? I'll appreciate any help.

I read the documentation and did not find an answer.

Comment: ReactFlow does not support this. This feature has been requested of the React Flow team multiple times in the past and every time I've seen the maintainers address it, they say that they will not add the feature (with no explanation as to "why not".). Until that sentiment changes, you will need to implement this yourself with custom Edges.

Comment: thank you, I will try to make a custom edge

Comment: @Max - did you succeed with this?

Comment: @Christian Added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Christian, I've created a very limited version of the feature. You can only move the horizontal part of the edge up and down. Vertical parts are not movable.

Link on the Github with the Edge implementation.
https://github.com/MaxKoldun/reactflow-midpoints-example/blob/main/CustomEdge.js

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. This is very helpful. Did you manage to do it on bezier curves as well?

Comment: no, for my project the step edge type was required so I did not consider other types.

But I think for the bezier type it should have the same drag and drop events but you need to modify coordinates calculations.

Comment: Thank you, @Max - appreciate your answers!